# Tracking the Usage Time doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am making a digital health app. I want it to count the unlock events and display the usage time. I was able to display the count the unlock events using a Receiver and a Service. I tried the same thing for the usage time, only that here, rather than incrementing a variable, each time the screen is turned on, it keeps the current time in a variable, and when the screen is turned off, it subtracts that variable from this moment current time. However, it doesn't seem to work.
My app is in french, so the Text View that should display the usage time is initialized to "0h et 0min".
However, to display it on the screen, I have used this type of format: 00:00:00

**The problem**: When I run my code, the value is changed to 00:00:00 and then nothing happens. Even after using the phone for quite some time, it still at 00:00:00.

I tried to see where the problem could come from, but after a few trials and no change whatsoever, here I am.
Here is my activity, called UserPageActivity:

```java
public class UserPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE=123;
    private deverouillageReceiver devReceiver;
    private TempsUseReceiver tempsUseReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super and view binding here 

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)
              != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            registerTempsUseReceiver();
        }
        startTempsUseService();
        
    }
    private void registerTempsUseReceiver(){
        tempsUseReceiver =new TempsUseReceiver();
        registerReceiver(tempsUseReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        registerReceiver(tempsUseReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permission, int[] grantResult) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permission, grantResult);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResult.length > 0 && grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                registerUnlockReceiver();
                registerTempsUseReceiver();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        BroadcastReceiver updateTotalTimeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals("com.example.digitalbalance1.STOP_TIME")) {
                    long totalTime = intent.getLongExtra("totalTime", 0);
                    updateTotalTimeTextView(totalTime);
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter updateTotalTimeFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.digitalbalance1.UPDATE_TOTAL_TIME");
        registerReceiver(updateTotalTimeReceiver, updateTotalTimeFilter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(tempsUseReceiver);
    }
    
    private void updateTotalTimeTextView(long totalTime){
        ui.useEdit.setText(convertMillisecondsToTime(totalTime));
    }
    public String convertMillisecondsToTime(long milliseconds) {
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds) % 60;
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds) % 60;
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds);

        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
    private void startTempsUseService(){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, TempsUseService.class);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.O ){
            startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        } else {
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The class extending BroadcastReceiver:

```java
public class TempsUseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private long countTime = 0;
    private long totalTime = 0;
    private boolean screenOn = true;
    //private static final String ACTION_COUNT_TIME = "com.example.digitalbalance1.COUNT_TIME";
    private static final String ACTION_STOP_TIME = "com.example.digitalbalance1.STOP_TIME";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Intent startCount = new Intent(context, TempsUseService.class);
            startCount.setAction(ACTION_STOP_TIME);
            context.startService(startCount);
            countTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("1"+countTime);
            screenOn=true;
        } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            if(screenOn){
                Intent endCount = new Intent(context, TempsUseService.class);
                endCount.setAction(ACTION_STOP_TIME);
                context.startService(endCount);
                long endCountTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("2"+endCountTime);
                long sessionTime = endCountTime-countTime;
                totalTime += sessionTime;
                updateTotalTime(context, totalTime);
            }
            screenOn=false;
        }
    }
    public long getCountTime(){return countTime;}
    
    public long getTotalTime(Context context){
        //return totalTime value that is in the file
    }
}
```

And finally my service class:

```java
public class TempsUseService extends Service {
    private TempsUseReceiver tempsUseReceiver;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
    private long totalTime = 0;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        tempsUseReceiver=new TempsUseReceiver();
        registerTempsUseReceiver();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        if(intent!=null && intent.getAction()!=null &&
        intent.getAction().equals("com.example.digitalbalance1.STOP_TIME")){
            long countTime= tempsUseReceiver.getCountTime();
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long sessionTime = currentTime - countTime;
            totalTime += sessionTime;
            updateTotalTime(this, totalTime);
        }
        else if (intent!=null && intent.getAction()!=null &&
                intent.getAction().equals("com.example.digitalbalance1.UPDATE_TOTAL_TIME")) {
            long updatedTotalTime = intent.getLongExtra("totalTime", 0);
            if (updatedTotalTime != 0) {
                totalTime = updatedTotalTime;
            }
        }
        updateTotalTimeInUserPageActivity(totalTime);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void updateTotalTimeInUserPageActivity(long totalTime) {
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent("com.example.digitalbalance1.STOP_TIME");
        updateIntent.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
        sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
    }
    private void registerTempsUseReceiver(){
        registerReceiver(tempsUseReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        registerReceiver(tempsUseReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }
    private void unregisterUnlockReceiver(){
        unregisterReceiver(tempsUseReceiver);
    }
  
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterUnlockReceiver();
    }
    private Notification createNotification() {
        //Notif creation
    }

    private void updateTotalTime(Context context, long totalTime) {
//write totalTime value in its file        
Intent("com.example.digitalbalance1.UPDATE_TOTAL_TIME");
        updateIntent.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
        context.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
}
    private File getTotalTimeFile(Context context){
        //retrieve totalTime value from its file
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Strip down both your prose and your code to the absolute *minimum* needed to show your issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque I just edited it to reduce what I think may be unnecessary (anything related to the count of unlock events since the problem isn't there)